# National pledge saying or singing?

Tags: word-choice, spoken-english, indian-english

In my school one student should say national pledge in the microphone, and the National pledge is like oath taking.

How should I refer this?
"He is saying national pledge" or "He is singing national pledge"..or something better and correct way to refer.

Comment: It could also be [reciting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recite) the pledge, or to "repeat from memory or read aloud publicly".  *The student recited the national pledge.*

Answer (score 3):

For your examples, usually a

> **pledge**

is spoken, where as an

> **anthem**

is sung.

Back in the day, at the beginning of very school day, the teacher might say

> [We will now **recite** the Pledge of Allegiance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kOEg55vewU&t=0m15s)
>   We will now **do** the Pledge of Allegiance
>   We will now **say** the Pledge of Allegiance

and at the beginning of most sports event someone will

> [**sing** the National Anthem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv2f5r5O0-c&t=0m27s)

Answer (score 1):

To cover both ideas in the question, I would

> take an oath

or

> make a pledge

In the second case I could also say

> give a pledge

More generally, a pledge can be an object, or a token, for example a marital engagement ring is a pledge, so I would not say that a pledge is something you *take*. You might receive one though.